# Select three tables and count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, I need to select email and count the relation between table A and table B, for example:

Table A:

```
 ID   |  email
 1    |  test@test
 2    |  test2@test
 3    |  test3@test
```

Table B:

```
UID   | username
11    | James
22    | Gabriel
33    | Jonas
```

Table C: (Relation between A and B)

```
  ID | email_id  | username_id
  1  |  1        | 11
  2  |  1        | 22
  3  |  2        | 33
```

Expect Result:

```
Email      | Totalrelation
test@test  | 2
test2@test | 1
```

I tried:

```
   select tableA.email, 
    COUNT(distinct tableC.email_id) AS total from tableA as tableA, tableC as tableC GROUP BY tableC.email_id
```

But it didnt work, I got total wrong. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables, group the data and count the number for each group

```
select a.email, count(c.id) as cnt
from tableA a
left join tableC c on c.email_id = a.id
group by a.email
```

Comment: I cant do it because C has only the email_id and A has the email value